# Why is my crontab command not working?

Tags: cron

I don't know what the problem is. I'm very confused.

**I'm using that command:**

```
crontab -e
```

**Crontab content:**

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
* * * * * /home/myuser/Belgeler/test.sh
```

(I've also tried like this: */1 * * * * /home/myuser/Belgeler/test.sh for schedule every minute)

**when I use on terminal, it's working perfectly:**

```
/home/myuser/Belgeler/test.sh
```

**test.sh file is here:**

```
#!/bin/sh
notify-send -i terminal "Notification test"
```

I don't know that the problem is..

**I've also gave the permissions with this code:**

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

**Edit:** Interesting but it's working with some commands like "mv (move)". But it isn't working with notify-send command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `DISPLAY` -variable. Change your script into

```
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send -i "Notification test"
```

#### Explanation

When you run the script from your own environment, a number of environment variables is automatically set. Cron however runs with a limited set of environment variables.

To run GUI applications (including `notify-send`) the `DISPLAY` variable is essential.

#### If you have more than one DISPLAY

In case you have more then one `DISPLAY` (if e.g. more users are logged in), The `DISPLAY` might not be `DISPLAY=:0`
If you regularly have more then one user logged in, you might have to include in your script parsing out the information of the command:

```
who -u
```

which produces lines like:

```
jacob    :0           2016-03-18 08:30   ?          2419 (:0)
```

As you can see, my `DISPLAY` is `:0`

Comment: I've found this problem when you're writing these lines.  :) thank you so much. it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the location of bash or sh :

```
* * * * * /bin/sh /home/myuser/Belgeler/test.sh
```

Otherwise, maybe you can see what the logs says to find an error:

```
# cat /var/log/syslog |grep cron
```

Comment: Thank you but /bin/sh isn't necessary. Also, when I use other command, everything seems normal in log file. :)